# Where in the Core is Layout Update XML from the Admin applied?

Tags: layout, core, layout-update

I'm trying to understand how Magento renders the custom layout xml that you can add to CMS pages or categories via the design tab. It seems to be applied after the theme's local.xml, but I can't find it.

I see `loadLayoutUpdates` in Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php at line 294-ish, but nothing there looks like it's getting anything from the database. (Custom layout updates *are* stored in the database, no?)

(To be clear, I'm not asking how to enter custom layout xml in the admin. Just wondering what's going on under the hood.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cms pages the layout is applied in [`Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::_renderPage()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php#L110).

For categories it happens in the view action of the [Category controller](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php#L140)
In both cases, the xml from the db is merged into the xml from the layout handles

Comment: Aha! Thank you! I missed it because I started off looking at the wrong controller.